# How can I make hover stage for odd and even table row

Tags: css, background, hover, css-tables

I want make hover stage for my table row. If Hover my mouse on row than background color should be change.

My CSS is this:

```
.tabuler_data {border-collapse:collapse;}
.tabuler_data td {border:solid 1px #ccc;}
.tabuler_data tr:nth-child(even) td, tbody tr.even td {background:#fff;}
.tabuler_data tr:nth-child(odd) td, tbody tr.odd td {background:#f5f5f5;}
.tabuler_data thead {background:#666;font:bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#fff;text-align:center;}
.tabuler_data th{border:solid 1px #ccc;}
```

Comment: I don't want to use javascript. is this possible without js. and i am using tr:nth-child(even) and (odd) so directly tr:hover is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<tr class="odd"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td></td></tr>
...
```

Hover

```
.tabuler_data tr:hover{background:#600000;}
```

You can also try...

```
.tabuler_data tr:hover td{background:#600000;}
```

Comment: ahah that's terrible. Check the OP's question, it shows how you can use `:nth-child([odd|even])` to avoid craziness like that

Comment: @david Are you saying that he doesn't know how to use :hover? I am aware of CSS selectors.

Comment: @webarto  .tabuler_data tr:hover{background:#60000;}  is not working. i have try it. :(

Comment: One zero is missing, it should be #600000 not #60000, try again, please.

Comment: @webarto no, I didn't say anything close to that :S I'm saying putting an 'odd'/'even' class on every single tr is not a good way to do it.

Comment: @david, I was kidding, I think title of question was different so I answered appropriately :) @kc_rajput, is it working?

Comment: @webarto thanks a lot .tabuler_data tr:hover td{background:#600000;} It's working.:)

Answer (score 8):

I find that this works:

```css
#order-table tr:hover:nth-child(odd)
{
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is probably that the specificity of your even/odd selectors is the same as the :hover selector. If you put the hover above the normal style it will get overwritten. Try doing this:

`.tabuler_data tr:nth-child(odd):hover td, tbody tr.odd:hover td {background:#f00;}`

Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/dwkEk/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this link would help you,

http://juicystudio.com/cognitive/example16.htm

http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/20011105/html/interactive/flat/css3-modsel-18.html

But I have never used it, and i usually do using javascript, easily done with jquery,

```
 $('table tr').hover(function (){
     $(this).css('background', 'red')}, 
                     function (){ 
      $(this).removeAttr('style');})
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfqDn/).

Without javascript [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zBcAr/). But it might not work with older versions of browsers.

Comment: I don't want to use javascript. is this possible without js.

Comment: @kcrajput it seems that it is possible http://jsfiddle.net/zBcAr/  works on latest chrome and firefox 3.6

Answer (score 0):

```
tr:hover { background: #aaa; }
```